# .net core 2.2 razor page view does not update correctly when remove object from collection

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Pretty new to asp .net core but trying to create a dapper crud grid and I can't figure out why when I remove a certain row from my list using a delete post handler it always returns the list with the last row removed instead of the one selected.

Debugging the OnPostDelete shows it removing the correct row from the list.
Tested RemoveAt working as expected in onget() but not onpostdelete.

below is most of my code behind cs file

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using RazorPagesExample.Entity;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using Dapper;

    namespace RazorPagesExample.Pages
    {

        public class multirowformModel : PageModel 
        {

            public class Proddaplocal
            {
                public int? Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public string Model { get; set; }
                public int Price { get; set; }
               public string Country { get; set; }
            }        

            [BindProperty]        
            public List<Proddaplocal> products { get; set; }        

            IConfiguration config;
            string connectionString;
            public multirowformModel(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                if (configuration != null)
                {
                    config = configuration;
                    connectionString = config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("ProductContext").Value;
                }            
            }
            public void OnGet()
            {            
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        var query = "SELECT Id,Name,Model,Price,Country FROM Product";
                        products = con.Query<Proddaplocal>(query).ToList();                 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            public IActionResult OnPostDelete(int? id)
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (id == null)
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    int delid = id ?? 0;
                    products.RemoveAt(delid);

                }

                return Page();
           }
       }
   }
```

below is my razor view

```
  @page
    @model RazorPagesExample.Pages.multirowformModel
    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "form table";
    }

    <h1>datatables</h1>

    <form id=multiform method="post" >
    <div class="table-responsive" style="max-width:800px">
        <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" style="width:30%;min-width:100px">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products[0].Name)
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="min-width:100px">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products[0].Model)
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width:15%; min-width:100px">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products[0].Price)
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="min-width:100px">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.products[0].Country)
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" style="min-width:50px">Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.products.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.products[i].Id" type="hidden" />
                            <input asp-for="@Model.products[i].Name" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.products[i].Model" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.products[i].Price" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.products[i].Country" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="table-action">                            
                            <img src="~/icons/trash.svg" title="Delete" alt="Delete" height="18" width="18" onclick="DeleteRow(@i,'@Model.products[i].Name')">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" asp-page-handler="Insert" value="Insert A">
            <i class="fas fa-save">Insert</i>
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" asp-page-handler="Update" value="Update A">
            <i class="fas fa-save">Save</i>
        </button>
    </div>
    </form>

    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/Javascript">
    <!--
    function DeleteRow(idno,desc) {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to Delete Row " + desc)) {
            $('#multiform').attr('action', "multirowform?handler=Delete&id=" + idno);
             $("#multiform").submit();
          } else {            
          }

    }

    </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding modelstate.clear() before removing the row fixed my issue.

```
        public IActionResult OnPostDelete(int? id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                int delid = id ?? 0;
                ModelState.Clear();
                products.RemoveAt(delid);
            }
            return Page();
       }
```

> "If you are getting your Model from a form and you want to manipulate the data that came from the client form and write it back to a view, you need to call ModelState.Clear() to clean the ModelState values." https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/modelstate-clear-is-required-to-display-back-your-model-object